# Seemingly unnecessary loop

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86

This was disassembled from a x86 exe that was (probably) created with MSVC.
Any reason for these loops or are they just bloat?

```
00428D08   |> B9 02000000    MOV ECX,2
00428D0D   |> 33C0           /XOR EAX,EAX
00428D0F   |> 8BF0           |/MOV ESI,EAX
00428D11   |. 48             ||DEC EAX
00428D12   |. 83F8 E9        ||CMP EAX,-17
00428D15   |.^7F F8          |\JG SHORT File.00428D0F
00428D17   |. 49             |DEC ECX
00428D18   |.^75 F3          \JNZ SHORT File.00428D0D
```

`ESI` is later on used in a sort of jump table, but this seems to me like an overly complicated way to set `ESI` twice

Comment: Is there a code behind it? Or you just got the asm?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it sets ESI from 0 to -17 twice. Resulting in ESI = -17.

Comment: Actually I just thought of something. Did you check whether it has any extra entry-points?

Comment: My guess would be either two cycles, but in this case somehow ineffectively compiled (or possibly commented out). Or it can be just bloat as you said. A payback for use of higher-level language. :D

Comment: @SmartK8 Resulting `esi` will be `-16`, not `-17`. Note that after `eax` reaches `-17` the last time (when `ecx` is `1`), the value of `eax` will not be copied anymore to `esi`. That way in the end `eax = -17`, `ecx = 0` and `esi = -16`. See my answer below.

Comment: That's either bad programming practice or an obfuscated code.

Comment: @nrz: You're right, the value -16 is stored in ESI, and the EAX is decremented for the last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no additional entry points and no self-modifying code, there is one unique way how the code can be walked through:

```
mov ecx,2              ; ecx = 2
xor eax,eax            ; eax = 0, ecx = 2, SF = 0, ZF = 0
mov esi,eax            ; eax = 0, ecx = 2, esi = 0, no changes to flags
dec eax                ; eax = 0xFFFFFFFF, ecx = 2, esi = 0, SF = 1, ZF = 0
cmp eax,-17            ; OF = 0, SF = 1, ZF = 0
jg SHORT File.00428D0F ; jump if (SF==OF and ZF==0) -> jump.
```

`mov esi, eax` ; `eax` = 0xFFFFFFFF, `ecx` = 2, `esi` = 0xFFFFFFFF
...
After 16 inner loops the situation is the following:

```
mov esi,eax            ; eax = -16, ecx = 2, esi = -16
dec eax                ; eax = -17, ecx = 2, esi = -16, SF = 1, ZF = 0
cmp eax,-17            ; OF = 0, SF = 0, ZF = 1
jg SHORT File.00428D0F ; jump if (SF==OF and ZF==0) -> no jump.
dec ecx                ; eax = -17, esi = -16, ecx = 1, SF = 0, ZF = 0
```

The outer loop is trivial. If it is certain that there are no other entry points except 00428D08 (the start of this code, `mov ecx,2`), that is code is not modified from somewhere else and that this code is not used as data, the code can be replaced with:

If flags' values are used after the end of this code:

```
mov eax,-17
cmp eax,-17
mov ecx,1
dec ecx
mov esi,-16
```

If flags' values are not important:

```
mov eax,-17
mov ecx,0
mov esi,-16
```